# Using Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE send multiple files through Bluetooth

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, file-transfer

I have seen some other example for using intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE. But they are example

all write for e-mail. My question is that I have about ten files to send,and I use intent

to send it via Bluetooth,I can successfully send those files to other device but it will

appear the intent chooser ten times,I just want it to appear just once or I can assign the

intent using Bluetooth in advance to send files,with not pop up any chooser. Can anybody

give me some suggestion?

The following is my code:

```
ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
    ArrayList<Uri> files = new ArrayList<Uri>(); 

    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(options, ","); 
     String stored = "";
        while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
            stored = tokens.nextToken();
            File file = new File(stored);
            fileList.add(file);
        }

        for(File file : fileList ) {
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            files.add(uri);
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "select some pic"));
    }
```

Thanks in advance for seeing my question!

Answer (score 1):

I finally find the answer , I add the following code and it works perfect

If anyone face the problem , maybe you can have a try!

```
intent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");
```

It would select Bluetooth to share files only and won't appear any

unnecessary intent chooser !